# Blank page when I try to edit an order address in Magento admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am running Magento 1.6.2.
When I click the Edit link above the shipping or billing address DIVs in the admin system, all I get is a blank page.
How do I figure out where the error is?
I have tried turning on template path hints (for the admin system), but because absolutely nothing is rendered when I click the link, I don't see any template info to even start to debug this issue?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Cheers!

Comment: please provide more details

Where you click **edit** 
in 
back end 
or front end

Comment: In the admin system (back end).

Answer (score 0):

You should enable developer mode in Magento to see the actual error printed. There are different ways to do it, the easiest one is to temporarily edit `index.php` and change

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

to

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

Then you should see the actual problem printed.

Comment: Thanks you, that helped - I now have an error log from the system that tells me something is trying to be parsed that shouldn't be. I have no idea how to progress this any further. All help and pointers would be appreciated. ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 15: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'  in /app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173

Comment: You need to debug the code and see, why the notification feed is broken. As a temporary solution you can replace `$xml  = new SimpleXMLElement($data);` with `$xml  = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>');` in that file at that line. This will disable the notifications feed, but at least will let you continue working.

Comment: Hi Andrey. I attempted this, but having cleared out all cache, sessions, etc, I still only get a blank page - and the error log that should be created in var/logs is not being created?? I am utterly stumped at the moment. Any further help would be appreciated.